# How can I tell to EJS if user is logged in?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

I'm trying to check if a user is logged in to display specifc content. I have this:

```
app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    res.render('profile', {
        user: req.user, isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn()
    });
});


function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next(null, true);
}
res.redirect('/');
}
```

And as template:

```
<%if (isLoggedIn) { %>
 <div>Content 1</div>
<% } %>
```

But I get this error:

> Cannot read property 'isAuthenticated' of undefined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check if your req.user exist or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isAuthenticated` of undefined meaning `req is undefined`.

here you are doing mistake.

```
user: req.user, isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn()
```

You can not call middleware function like this. `isLoggedIn()`

What you can do is:

```
app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
     res.render('profile', {
          user: req.user, isLoggedIn: req.isLogged
     });
});


function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
     if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        req.isLogged = true
        return next();
     }
     res.redirect('/');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

isLoggedIn function is a middleware. It doesn't returns true or false here and you should simply use req.isAuthenticated() that returns true or false if the user is authenticated or not. Here is code :-

```
app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    res.render('profile', {
        user: req.user, isLoggedIn:req.isAuthenticated()
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is to just look at whether the variable `user` is defined.

```
res.render('profile', {
    user: req.user
});
```

and in your view:

```
<% if(typeof user != 'undefined') { %>
    // do stuff
<% } %>
```